# Extjs 4 charts display problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, charts, extjs4, extjs

I am trying to implement ExtJS 4 charts with rails, but getting the following error :

```
Error : Uncaught Ext.Error: No theme found named "Base"
```

Tried adding     `requires:['Ext.chart.*']` as per Sencha's forum, but no luck.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance !

Edit : How to render GoogleCharts on Extjs 4 Panel??

Answer (score 2):

Same problem as described, but putting `Ext.require(['Ext.chart.*']);` in my source code solves it for me...